# sendActionsForControlEvents: from another view controller is not working

Tags: xcode

I have the search bar , on click on search bar ill get the storyboard popover , popover has a search button which bring push view controller ,
now the problem is , on click on search bar keyboard ‘search’ button , i need to get the push view controller on popover

first View Controller

enter code here

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
 [searchBar resignFirstResponder];    
 secondViewController *secondView = [[secondViewController alloc] init];
 [secondView.searchButton sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    

}
```

second View Controller

enter code here

```
- (IBAction)searchButton:(id)sender {

    UIViewController *thirdView=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"thirdViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdView animated:YES];

}
```